# Button not running event in Kivy App

Tags: android, python, kivy

I have created a two button code for a simple Kivy app, but on clicking the button, it is unable to run a method.

When I click on 'Check in' button, it says **AttributeError: 'Button' object has no attribute 'login'**

Here is my code. I want to print a message on clicking button.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

button1 = '''
BoxLayout:

    Button:
        text: 'Check In'
        height: "40dp"
        on_press: login()
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .1, 'center_y': .1}  
        canvas.before:
            PushMatrix
            Rotate:
                angle: 0
                origin: self.center
        canvas.after:
            PopMatrix
    Button:
        text: 'SOS'
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .1, 'center_y': .1}
        canvas.before:
            PushMatrix
            Rotate:
                angle: 0
                origin: self.center
        canvas.after:
            PopMatrix
'''



class RotationApp(App):

    def build(self):

        return Builder.load_string(button1)
    def login(self):
        print("Click the goddamn button")
RotationApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button doesn't have a reference to the login method - as far as it's concerned that's just some random name that could have come from anywhere.

Since login is a method of your app class, you need a reference to the running app, which luckily kv language already provides with the `app` keyword. That means you should replace `login` with `app.login`.

You can also get a reference to the app in pure python via `App.get_running_app()`, which is in fact what the app keyword does behind the scenes.

Comment: Excellent. Looks like you are the only one on stackoverflow who know kivy. :) This prints my message, but not as a pop up, it prints on console. What can I do to displaying message as a pop up?

Comment: `Popup().open()`. You can also look at the documentation to see how to set the title of the popup or add widgets to it.

Comment: Again Thanks. Can I call any function from any other file( .py) in same folder?

Comment: Yes, this is just normal python, you need to import the other file as a module.